# Array keeps dropping first number in index

Tags: javascript, arrays

Sorry for the ugliness. I'm trying to write code that will, at this point, take a list of phone numbers as strings, and find the sum of their digits and put it into a new array. I'm feeling good about it, but when I run it I get an array with only the latter sums, not the first in the index.

```
var numList = ["555-237-4892", "555-236-44892", "233-482-1049"];
var penList = [];
for (var j = 0; j < numList.length; j++) {
    function sum() {
        var phonestr = numList[j];
        var phoneArray = phonestr.split("");
        delete phoneArray[3];
        delete phoneArray[7];
        phoneArray.sort();
        phoneArray.pop();
        phoneArray.pop();

        var total = 0;
        var phoneInt;

        var largest = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < phoneArray.length; i++) {
            phoneInt = parseInt(phoneArray[i]);
            total += phoneInt;

        }
        penList[i] = total;

    };
    sum();
};
console.log(penList);
```

Comment: Don't apologize for the ugliness. Just fix your formatting prior to posting. A little effort from the asker goes a long way here.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you're trying to do, I think you want to change this:

```
penList[i] = total;
```

to this:

```
penList[j] = total;
```

---

And, here's a much more condensed way of doing it:

```js
var numList = ["555-237-4892", "555-236-44892", "233-482-1049"];

var result = numList.map(function(item) {
  return item.replace(/\D/g, "").split("").reduce(function(total, ch) {
    return total + parseInt(ch, 10);
  }, 0);
});

// display result in snippet
document.write(JSON.stringify(result));
```

Explanation:

1. Call map on `numList` so it will iterate through the array
2. To create a new array where the non-digits are removed with `.replace()`
3. And split into a sub-array of characters with `.split()`
4. And then summed using .reduce()
5. All resulting in an array of the digit totals

Answer (score 0):

Change `penList[i]` to `penList[j]` in your outer for loop.

Also, if there's no need, you don't need to declare a `sum()` function within your for loop if you are just going to call it right away. If you're doing it to modularize your code, it's best if you move that function out of the loop for better readability.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

> > follow on comments for explanation

```
var numList = ["555-237-4892","555-236-44892","233-482-1049"];
var penList = [];
for (var j = 0; j < numList.length; j++) {
    function sum() {
        var phonestr = numList[j];
        var phoneArray = phonestr.split("");
        //remove the first "-" from array
        // now you have 1 char less in array
        phoneArray.splice(3, 1);
        //remove the second "-" from array
        //the second '-' is not at index 7 since we already removed 1index in previous step its at index 6
        phoneArray.splice(6, 1); 
        phoneArray.sort();
        phoneArray.pop();
        phoneArray.pop();

        var total = 0;
        var phoneInt;
        var largest = 0;

        for (var i = 0; i < phoneArray.length; i++) {
            phoneInt = parseInt(phoneArray[i]);
            total += phoneInt;
        } 
        //this should be j not i since we are in ouer loop
        penList[j] = total;

   }; 
       sum(); 
};
```